# How to import a large .csv file into sqlite - memory issues with sqlite Manager

Tags: sql, sqlite, csv

I am having some issues trying to import a 2GB .csv file into sqlite. The .csv file has a large number of columns, and I have tried to use sqlite manager as this provides a way to create a table with the correct column names in sqlite.

However, when I try to import the .csv file in sqlite manager I run into memory issues for some reason, and the import fails. I get 'Fatal error: Out of memory'.

Are there any ways that I can get round this? I thought about splitting up the file into chunks but don't know how to do this without having to open the file itself and encountering issues with memory.

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've encountered a known bug in sqlite-manager - see [issue 414:out of memory error when trying to import a large (268MB) CSV file](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/issues/detail?id=414) in the project's issue tracker.

If your failed import with sqlite-manager still gives you an empty table with the correct column names, I'd open up that database file in the sqlite shell and use the built-in `.import` function to get your data in.

If that's not an option for you or if you're determined to get through this with sqlite-manager, then your notion to split up the CSV file is right on.

Depending on your platform, you have a lot of options for splitting up your file. There's a lot of Windows freeware out there for this(like [GSplit](http://www.gdgsoft.com/gsplit/)), and your should find the `split` utility on just about any Unix-like machine.